# Assign Task to Multiple Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

In Redmine it's possible to assign One Task to multiple users.

http://www.redmine.org/issues/408

I think discussion is going on anybody have nice solution to manage this one step by step.

Answer (score 2):

If your read the the linked issue carefully, you'll see that it has been closed and that this feature has never been developed.

The developer team is thinking about implementing a possibility to assign an issue to a user group (see http://www.redmine.org/issues/2964 ).

Therefore the correct answer is that there is no step-by-step solution to assign a task to multiple users.